# How to solve exc Bad access thread when click on UiButton?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibutton

I am new to iOS development, My app is crashing in button Click. I am getting an error 'exc Bad access thread'.Please Show the image what app really caused

Here is my code

```
if(self.VKPlayer != nil)
    {
        if(self.isPlayerMuted == false)
        {
            self.isPlayerMuted = true;
            self.VKPlayer.setMute(true);
            button.selected = true;
        }
        else
        {
            self.isPlayerMuted = false;
            self.VKPlayer.setMute(false);
            button.highlighted = true;
            button.selected = false;
        }
    }
```

Please Help me..

Comment: Check with your button IBAction.

Comment: Which line exactly causes the crash?

Comment: enable breakpoint exception and see the exact reason of crash

Comment: I am getting an thread error of BAD_EXC_ACCESS with AUREMOTEIO::IO

Comment: did you enable breakpoint exception in Xcode?

Comment: Yaa.I enable it..but also causes...

Answer (score 0):

Put a break point in your `IBAction` to see if that get triggered. Also check if any of the codes in the IBAction is wrong.

If your code looks right, check if you have dead connections. Right click on the view controller icon on the storyboard and remove any connection with a yellow arrow. Then connect again.